# Как ускорить код python?

Tags: python

Не могу ускорить код (нужно хотя бы на 0.1 сек быстрее).

> Задание:
> (`insert number` – добавляет заданное число в конец списка
> `delete number` – удаляет первое вхождение заданного числа из списка. Если список не содержит заданного числа, то ничего не меняется.)

> Напишите программу, которая по последовательности операций добавления и удаления в пустой список, определяет после каждой из операций, является ли список гомогенным или гетерогенным.

> `homo` = есть хотя бы 2 одинак числа,
> `hetero` = есть хотя бы 2 различных числа,
> `both` = 2 одинак числа, и 2 различных числа,
> `neither` = никакой.

> Входные данные:
> Первая строка содержит целое число n – количество операций;
> Следующие n строк содержат описания операций. Каждая операция описывается словом “`insert`” или “`delete`” и числом k – аргументом операции.

```
    q=int(input())
    o=0
    sp=[]
    while o!=q:
        c1=0
        c2=0
        a=str(input())
        a=a.split(' ')
        if a[0]=='insert':
            sp.append(int(a[1]))
        else:
            if int(a[1]) in sp:
                sp.remove(int(a[1]))
        if (len(sp)<2):
            print("neither")
        else:
            b=sp.count(max(set(sp), key=sp.count))
            if (b>1 and b!=len(sp)):
                    print("both")
            elif (b>1 and b==len(sp)):
                    print("homo")
            elif (b==1 and len(sp)>1):
                print("hetero")
        o+=1
```

Comment: Используйте словарь со счётчиками, или готовый Counter

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас ваша программа имеет асимптотическую сложность `O(N^3)`. Данная сложность достигается на тесте, когда вставляются все числа от 1 до N. Тогда, начиная со второй итерации, будет выполняться строка `b=sp.count(max(set(sp), key=sp.count))`, которая сначала создает `set(sp)` размером `o + 1`, а потом для каждого его элемента проходит по списку размера `o + 1`. В итоге сложность будет `O(sum(i^2) for i in 1..n) = O(N^3)`

Чтобы просто ускорить вашу программу, достаточно заменить эту строку. Прямо эквивалентным будет использование `Counter` из модуля `collections`: `collections.Counter(sp).most_common(1)[1]`. Ну или можно использовать любую другую линейную замену, как например в [ответе maestro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1376696/394856). В итоге вы получите сложность O(N^2), что точно ускорит вас на 0.1 секунды. (Хотя я подозреваю, что на самом деле вы сдавали в тестирующую систему, которая просто обрубила выполнение вашей программы при превышении времени, так что 0.1 секунды вам бы не помогло)

Но я также хотел бы предложить свое решение работающее за O(N):

```
from sys import stdin, stdout
from collections import defaultdict
my_input = stdin.readline
my_print = stdout.write


n = int(my_input())
nums = defaultdict(int)
count = 0
for it in range(n):
    op, x = my_input().split()
    if op[0] == 'i':
        nums[x] += 1
        if nums[x] == 2:
            count += 1
    else:
        if x in nums:
            nums[x] -= 1
            if nums[x] == 1:
                count -= 1
            elif nums[x] == 0:
                nums.pop(x)

    if count >= 2:
        if len(nums) >= 2:
            print('both')
        else:
            print('homo')
    else:
        if len(nums) >= 2:
            print('hetero')
        else:
            print('neither')
```

К сожалению, тестов вы не привели, поэтому я не гарантирую, что решение сразу будет работать как надо, но не думаю, что я налажал в идее.

А идея следующая: хоть в задании и сказано, что добавлять элементы нужно в список, но на самом деле вам нужно только знать количество вхождений каждого числа в каждый момент времени, а их порядок вам неважен. Поэтому эффективнее будет использовать словарь, в котором будет поддерживаться количество вхождений каждого числа. Чтобы отвечать, является ли на текущий момент список "гомогенным", я также поддерживаю количество чисел, которые входят в список хотя бы два раза.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    what, num = input().split()
    if what == 'insert':
        lst.append(num)
    else:
        if num in l:
            l.remove(num)
    uni = set(lst)
    homo, het = None, len(uni) > 1
    for i in uni:
        if lst.count(i) > 1:
            homo = True
            break
    if homo and het:
        print('both')
    elif homo and not het:
        print('homo')
    elif not homo and het:
        print('hetero')
    else:
        print('neither')
```

Comment: Спасибо, но нужно быстрее.

Comment: Если хочешь быстрее то пиши на плюсах.

Answer (score 0):

```py
n = int(input())
sp = []
for _ in range(n):
  command, k = input().split()
  k = int(k)
  if command == "insert":
    sp.append(k)
  elif command == "delete":
    if k in sp:
      sp.remove(k)
  res = ""
  if len(sp)<2:
    res = "neither"
  else:
    unic = len(set(sp))
    homo = len(sp) != unic # есть ли одинаковые
    hetero = len(set(unic)) > 1 # есть ли разные
    if homo and hetero:
        res = 'both'
    elif homo and not hetero:
        res = 'homo'
    elif not homo and hetero:
        res = 'hetero'
    else:
        res = 'neither'
  print(res)
```